# In react server side application do we need to make API calls twice, one at server side and another at client side

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactJS application, where our home page is rendered using server side rendering and I need to make an API call. I need to know do we have to make API call on server side or on client side or both the side

Comment: No, just once, the server side processes the initial call and sends the output out

Comment: Also client side can do the same, but you only do the call one side and not both